# mysql: How to update many to many relation table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, cakephp-2.0

I am using Cakephp for website development, now I have this table

```
id|student_id|specialization_id
```

Now my question is how to update this table, currently I am deleting all previous data of a particular student and add new specialization given by the student.

Comment: provide more information about what you want to do with you table... There is a very easy way to update tables information by giving conditions...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do that seems like a reasonable way of doing it. If you dont want to delete the previous specialization data consider adding a timestamp and in your queries only select the most recent one.